# A question about definition of field in book *A Probability Path*

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

In book *A Probability Path*, the author defines a field just like this:

> A field is a non-empty class of subsets of $\Omega$ closed under finite union,finite intersection and complements.

In the following, he says like this:

> A minimal set of postulates for $\ A$ to be a field is (i)$\Omega \in A.$(ii)$T \in A $ implies $\overline{T} \in A.$(iii)$S,T \in A $ implies $S\cup T \in A$

Though I know why it exactly defines a field, the author says nothing about why they are minimal. He even uses the word minimal without an exact definition. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 5):

The postulates are minimal becasue no two of them implies the third one. To see this we have to produce counter-examples.

1. The empty collection satisfies (ii) and (iii) (vacuously)  but does not satisfy (i).
2. $\{\mathbb R, [0,1],  [0,2]$} $ satisfies (i) and (iii) but not (ii)
3. $\{\mathbb R, [0,1], [0,2], \mathbb R\setminus [0,1],\mathbb R\setminus [0,2],\emptyset\} $ satisfies (i) and (ii) but not (iii)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Through your examples, now I know what the minimal means.